# Why does this function return a pointer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When I call this function, it seems to return a pointer instead of an int. When I try and NSLog the return value, I get a warning "passing argument 1 of NSLog from incompatible pointer type." And if the NSLog runs, it crashes.

Does this have to do with this being a static method? How can I get back a real int?

I am using SDK 3.0

Here is the function in question:

```
+(int) getZoomFromExtent: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)bottomLeft
            withTopRight:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)topRight
             withPixelsX:(int)pixelsX 
             withPixelsY:(int)pixelsY 
         withMapContents: (RMMapContents*) contents;
```

Here is the .h code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <math.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CLLocation.h>
#import "RMTile.h"
#import "RMMapContents.h"

@interface AnnasMath : NSObject {}

+(CLLocationCoordinate2D) normalizePixelCoords:(CLLocationCoordinate2D) point;
+(RMTile)tileWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)point andZoom:(int)zoom;
+(NSArray *)getTileArrayWithUpperLeft:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)upperLeft andLowerRight: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)lowerRight fromZoom:(int)bottomZoom toZoom:(int)topZoom;
+(int)getTileCountWithUpperLeft:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)upperLeft andLowerRight:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)lowerRight fromZoom:(int)bottomZoom toZoom:(int)topZoom;
+(int) getZoomFromExtent: (CLLocationCoordinate2D)bottomLeft 
             withTopRight:   (CLLocationCoordinate2D)topRight
              withPixelsX:(int)pixelsX
              withPixelsY:(int)pixelsY
          withMapContents: (RMMapContents*) contents;
```

@end

Here is the beginning of the .m code:

```
#import "AnnasMath.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <math.h>
#import "TileWrapper.h"

@implementation AnnasMath

...
```

I am using it as follows:

```
int zoom = [AnnasMath getZoomFromExtent:[[extent objectForKey:@"bottomLeft"]coordinate] 
               withTopRight:[[extent objectForKey:@"topRight"]coordinate]
                            withPixelsX:300
                            withPixelsY:300 
                        withMapContents:t.mapVC.mapView.contents];

NSLog("About to set the zoom to %i", zoom);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice that it says "argument 1" — whereas the variable you're looking at is argument 2. You're passing a C string as the first argument of NSLog rather than an NSString (which is written like `@"something"` rather than just `"something"`).

Answer (score 1):

The correct string is:

```
NSLog(@"About to set the zoom to %i", zoom);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you function is returning an int as you wish.

The compile warning you are recieving is actually the string argument to NSLog... it expects an Objective-C String, and you are passing it a Cstring.

add a @ before the string and all should be well.